# Extract table name from sql query using sql query?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

How to extract table name from any SQL query, using SQL query?

I have solution using Python SQL Parse library, but I need it using SQL query.

Comment: What do you mean? An example would help..

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If we have sql query- select * from stl_query;      Here, tablename is "stl_query", so, I need a sql query, through which I can extract table name ("stl_query") from query.

Comment: Put simply, that is not really what SQL is for. Why do you need to extract the table name? And why does your parser need to be written in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your DB Name

```
SELECT DISTINCT
table_name
FROM
information_schema.columns
WHERE
table_schema = 'your_database_name'
AND column_name IN (
    SELECT
        column_name
    FROM
        information_schema.columns
    WHERE
        table_schema = 'your_database_name'
        AND LOWER(column_name) LIKE '%select%'
);
```

Comment: While the OP's intent is not fully clear, I don't think this addresses the question they have put forth.